# Which Fleet Management Software exists for IoT devices?

Tags: linux, over-the-air-updates

I would like to ask what kind of fleet management software exists for IoT devices.

I know:

1. resin.io
2. mender.io
3. Teamviewer IoT (RPI only)

Are there more services like this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi zer02, unfortunately Stack Exchange is neither very good at list questions nor are you defining what you understand under *fleet management*. From my experience in the industry people understand widely different things when they talk about that. From your tagging and your linked projects it looks like you are mainly interested in updating devices.

Comment: Hello, updating, maintenance services, where I can see my devices, which are online (and access them optional).

Comment: It isn't clear what you're after. Please read [these guidelines on asking for software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and edit your question accordingly. What features do you want from fleet management, what types of devices, how many devices, whether you'd want to host your own software or you're looking for a service, how much you're prepared to pay, …?

Comment: I've put your question temporarily on hold, @zer02, so you can review the guidelines Gilles linked and [edit] to include a little more information. Let me know when you've done this and I can reopen your question, and you should be able to get much more specific answers that way.

Comment: @Giles, I think this question would be better asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Do you concur? I am unsure how it could be editted to make it on topic here.